# How to Migrate data from D2 documentum to alfresco?

Tags: migration, alfresco, ecm, alfresco-webscripts

I have some content in D2 Documentum. and i want to migrate all those content with meta-data in alfresco.

can any one help me.

how can i achieve this in alfresco.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools available to handle Database/CMS migrations. If both repositories are CMIS compliant the problem becomes even easier to address. I read an interesting article about doing an Alfresco to Nuxeo migration using Apache's Chemistry and Camel offerings. [Check it out.](http://keytocontent.blogspot.com/2014/11/cmis-document-migration-with-apache.html)

One tool that makes migrating between ECMs very simple is [Simflofy](https://www.simflofy.com/). They have connectors OOTB for CMIS compliant repositories and a very handy UI that allows easy mapping of properties. This particular tool is very fast as it was developed on a new technology stack that takes advantage multithreading and gives full audit support/reporting.

**Full Disclosure**: I work for a [company](http://www.fikatechnologies.com/) that does several migrations a year using Simflofy.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how many documents you need to export.

A simple answer can be: do a bulk export from Documentum and a bulk import in Alfresco.

There are several tools to export documents and metadata from Documentum. I used only a proprietary tool in my experience, but I do not think it will be difficult to find one.

For the import in Alfresco you can use the [OOTB Bulk import](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/Bulk-Import-Tool.html)

As you can see, you will probably need to write a small application to transform the export to the predefined format that the bulk import accepts.